# INDEX Column Reference vs Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I modify the following formula work in a specified range without causing `#REF` errors if the rows are deleted in the referenced sheet? I am experiencing a lot of lag when inputting data and I believe it's due to referencing entire columns vs a specified range. I am looking for the range to be `$D11:D$300`.

Here is my formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(contactunder!D:D,ROW(),0),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indirect.

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(indirect("contactunder!D1:D300"),ROW(),0),0)
```

Note I haven't tested this, Google indirect if I got the syntax wrong